# Vapnik-Chervonenkis Dimension: why cannot four points on a line be shattered by rectangles?

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

So I'm reading *"Introduction to Machine Learning"* 2nd edition, by Bishop, et. all.  On page 27 they discuss the Vapnik-Chervonenkis Dimension which is,

> *"The maximum number of points that can be shattered by H [the hypothesis class] is called the Vapnik-Chervonenkis (VC) Dimension of H, is denoted VC(H) and measures the capacity of H."*

Whereas "shatters" indicates a hypothesis $h \in H$ for a set of N data points such that it separates the positive examples from the negative.  In such an example it is said that "H shatters N points".

So far I think I understand this.  However, the authors lose me with the following:

> *"For example, four points on a line cannot be shattered by rectangles."*

There must be some concept here I'm not fully understanding, because I cannot understand why this is the case.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Call the four points $p,q,r,s$ in order along the line.  There is no rectangle that contains $p$ and $r$ but excludes $q$ and $s$.

Comment: Yes, but there are rectangles that can contain $p$ and $q$, excluding $r$ and $s$; or contain $q$ and $r$ and exclude $p$ and $s$.  Are you saying that each combination must be possible for the points to be shattered, and if so WHY IS THIS NOT AN ANSWER :P ?

Comment: I don't get the answer and I believe your point is right bro @BrotherJack can you explain why I am wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definition of "a set $P$ can be [shattered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shattering_%28machine_learning%29) by rectangles" is that for **every** subset of $P$, there is a rectangle that contains precisely that subset and excludes the rest of $P$. Equivalently, every labeling of the points as positive and negative is consistent with at least one hypothesis in $H$.

Now consider four points $p,q,r,s$ along a line in the plane.  Since there is no rectangle that contains $p$ and $r$ but excludes $q$ and $s$, these four points cannot be shattered by rectangles.

Comment: There we go.  Much better to have this as an answer, no?